# Compact Embedding/ Sobolev's Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, smooth-functions

I have a domain given $\Omega =[0,1]^2$ and need a compact embedding in $C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ for my function in $H^3(\Omega)$.
We have $N=2$, so i tried to get the embedding with the help of Sobolev's embedding theorem. However, for this $\partial \Omega$ must be in $C^1$. For $\Omega$ we have the square $[0,1]^2$, this has corners and therefore no smooth edge. Does a compact embedding still apply to this?

Answer (score 4):

The embedding is true for Lipschitz domains and not just $C^1$ domains. This is because if you have a Lipschitz domain, you can extend a function in $H^3(\Omega)$ to a function in $H^3(\mathbb{R}^2)$ controlling the norm. This extension is due to Stein.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for such a theorem!
Is the following statement true now:
   
 It holds $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ and has now no more smooth boundary, however it is, a Lipschitz domain. If we use Stein's continuation theorem accordingly, we can continue to work with Sobolev's embedding theorem. For $n=2$, $k=3$ and $m=1$ we have 
    $$m<k-\frac{n}{2}$$
    and the compact embedding.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Could you give a reference for this method of Stein? And does the proof have to do with Kirezbraun theorem?

Comment: Theorem 13.17 in https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-181 and no, it is significantly more complicated

Comment: I have now searched for suitable literature or sources. I have found only sentences in which the domain must be open and bounded. Then it is sufficient if it is a Lipschitz domain. So my domain has to be $(0,1)^2$  right?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There are many bounded and Lipschitz domains that are not a square. Any polygon is bounded and Lipschitz

Comment: I would like to have a square as the domain. However, [0,1]^2 is not open and accordingly I choose (0,1)^2 as the domain, omit the corners accordingly and get an open domain. Since this is a condition according to the literature.

Comment: Yes, you need open sets